# Return query name Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

In an already existing table I would like to create a new column containing the name of the query I am using.

For example:

```
ID  Name 
-----------
1   Max
2   Jack
```

The desired output is:

```
ID Name  Query
-------------------
1  Max   QueryName
2  Jack   QueryName
```

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT ID, NAME, "QueryName" AS Query FROM yourTable` ?

Comment: I would like to have the actual name of the Query (the name I used to save the Query in Access). This name will eventually change and I would like to avoid going into the query to change it manually

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a static value field in your query, like this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, "QueryName" AS Query
FROM yourTable;
```

---

When you just want to add a column with a static value in result of querying a table, above is the solution, If you want to create a *Query* with a special *name* then use it, just use its name in its query in creation time.
I mean when you are changing name of a query; also edit its query with using that name.

But, I don't think this is a good idea to store a query then change its name and use its name as a result of its query or other queries, It seems you want to store a string value somewhere then use it by adding it in another query, So:

1. Create another table(QueryTable) like:

   ```
   QueryId | QueryName
   --------+--------------
   1       | Query Name 1
   2       | Query Name 2
   ```
2. Use it in your other queries:

   ```
   SELECT t.*, q.QueryName
   FROM yourTable t CROSS JOIN QueryTable q
   WHERE q.QueryId = 1;
   ```

And I suggest this because it's better to use a tool in its using zone, when you want to store data and use it result some information; use a table for that. HTH ;).

Comment: I would like to have the actual name of the Query (the name I used to save the Query in Access). This name will eventually change and I would like to avoid going into the query to change it manually