# MS Access, use query name as field default value

Tags: database, ms-access

My department uses a software tool that can use a custom component library sourced from Tables or Queries in an MS Access database.

```
Table: Components
  ID:   AutoNumber
  Type: String
  Mfg:  String
  P/N:  String
  ...

Query: Resistors
  SELECT Components.*
  FROM Components
  WHERE Components.Type = "Resistors"

Query: Capacitors
  SELECT Components.*
  FROM Components
  WHERE Components.Type = "Capacitors"
```

These queries work fine for SELECT. But when users add a row to the query, how can I ensure the correct value is saved to the Type field?

Comment: If you want to constrain data entry, use a form, not a query. You can't constrain data entry on queries.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit #2:

Nope, can't be done.  Sorry.

---

### Edit #1:

As was pointed out, I may have misunderstood the question.  It's not a *wonky* question after all, but perhaps an easy one?

If you're asking how to add records to your table while making sure that, for example, "the record shows up in a Resistors query if it's a Resistor", then it's a regular append query, that specifies `Resisitors` as your `Type`.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO Components ( ID, Type, Mfg )
SELECT 123, 'Resistors', 'Company XYZ'
```

If you've already tried that and are having problems, it could be because you are using a Reserved Word as a field name which, although it may work sometimes, can cause problems in unexpected ways.

`Type` is a word that Access, SQL and VBA all use for a specific purpose.  It's the same idea as if you used `SELECT` and `FROM` as field or table names.  (`SELECT SELECT FROM FROM`).

Here is a [list of reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) that should generally be avoided. (I realize it's labelled Access 2007 but the list is very similar, and it's surprisingly difficult to find an recent 'official' list for Excel VBA.)

---

**Original Answer:**

That's kind a a wonky way to do things.  The point of databases is to organize in such a way as to prevent duplication of not only data, but queries and codes as well

I made up the programming rule for my own use *"If you're doing anything more than once, you're doing it wrong."*  (That's not true in *all* cases but a general rule of thumb nonetheless.)

Are the only options "`Resistors`" and "`Capacitors`"?  (...I hope you're not tracking the inventory of an electronics supply store...)  If there are may options, that's even more reason to find an alternative method.

To answer your question, in the Query Design window, it is **not possible** to return the name of the open query.

## Some alternative options:

- <del>As @Erik suggested</del>, constrain to a control on a form. Perhaps have a drop-down or option buttons which the user can select the relevant type.  Then your query would look like:

  `SELECT * FROM Components WHERE Type = 'Forms![YourFormName]![NameOfYourControl]'`
- In VBA, have the query refer to the value of a variable, foe example:

  `Dim TypeToDel as String`
  `TypeToDel = "Resistor"`
  `DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * FROM Components WHERE Type = '" & typeToDel'"`
- Not recommended, but you could have the user manually enter the criteria.  If your query is like this:

  `SELECT * FROM Components WHERE Type = '[Enter the component type]'`

  ...then each time the query is run, it will prompt:

  [image: img]
- Similarly, you could have the query prompt for an option, perhaps a single-digit or a code, and have the query choose the the appropriate criteria:

  [image: img2]

...and have an `IF` statement in the query criteria.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Components 
WHERE Type = IIf([Enter 1 for Resistors, 2 for Capacitors, 3 for sharks with frickin' laser beams attached to their heads]=1,'Resistors',IIf([Enter 1 for Resistors, 2 for Capacitors, 3 for sharks with frickin' laser beams attached to their heads]=2,'Capacitors','LaserSharks'));
```

Note that if you're going to have more than 2 options, you'll need to have the parameter box more than once, and they must be spelled identically.

- Lastly, if you're still going to take the route of a separate query for each component type, as long as you're making separate queries *anyway*, why not just put a static value in each one (just like your example):

  `SELECT * FROM Components WHERE Type = 'Resistor'`

There's another wonky answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483396/return-query-name-access-sql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but that's just creating even more duplicate information (and more future mistakes).

---

**Side note**: ***`Type`*** is a reserved word in Access & VBA; you might be best to choose another.  (I usually prefix with a related letter like `cType`.)

---

### More Information:

- **[Use parameters in queries, forms, and reports](http://ttps//support.office.com/en-ie/article/use-parameters-in-queries-forms-and-reports-8209eb5c-1589-42e2-9b20-4181f4c7a356)**
- **[Use parameters to ask for input when running a query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed)**
- **[Microsoft Access Tips & Tricks: Parameter Queries](http://blogannath.blogspot.ca/2010/02/microsoft-access-tips-tricks-parameter.html)**
   <sub><sup>• [Frickin' Lasers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bh7bYNAHXxw)</sup></sub>

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the question, and my comment. As far as I understand, the question, as I understand it, is: OP only wants people to be able to add new entries to the _Resistors_ query where _Type_ if the type is set to "Resistors", and only add new entries to _Capacitors_ where if the type is set to "Capacitors".

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth ...well that makes a relatively useless answer *even less* useful.  Hmm, "add new entries to a query", huh?  *\*sigh\**  (So much for breaking 6k today on these types of questions; gonna make me work for it, lol)

Comment: Well, I appreciate the effort. If you keep up the way you're going, you might exceed my rep soon :).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth (lol I don't know about that, but I'd better check...next I'll query your rate of rep increase compared to mine and let you know an ETA...)    But so, he's just asking how to write an append query then?

Comment: Nope, he's asking for something that can't be done. If you're executing a fully updateable query off a single table, you can add records when viewing the data in datasheet view. You can add records that would not be returned by your query, because they violate the `WHERE` clause. He wants to change that to only add records that meet the `WHERE` clause. But this can't be done, since queries aren't intended for data entry and have no way to validate the data entered (well, it probably can be done with some advanced data macro + VBA trickery, but it shouldn't be done)

Comment: Gotcha.  I give up on this one.  On to query your rep.  (What, I'm not *that* competitive... I just thought there was an extra `0` behind your score. It's good to have goals and this one *might* be attainable; not sure yet...)  Perhaps after that, time to call the optometrist.

Comment: Exactly right Erik, thanks for clarifying. I like the rule about duplication. Unfortunately, the software requires either a table or query for each component type. We use Excel now, with one sheet-table per component type (we have ~10 types). All the common fields are duplicated, and I'm trying to eliminate that using Access. It sounds like the best route is 1) some table structure 2) custom queries for the software 3) custom forms for users. Does that sounds right?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth - October 25, 2019. That's the day I overtake you. I'll reach 28,811 and you'll "only" have 28,810...so you're good for a little while yet.